# Pure PHP rrdtool

Tags: php, rrdtool

does anyone know a pure-php implementation of rrdtool? I googled this question, but only found answers about interfacing PHP & rrd...

Comment: rrdtool is more of a brand than a type of application, so the question is a little odd as worded. rrdtool requires lower level access than "pure-php" can provide. How is a PHP interface not adequate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it probably defeats the purpose.
While I see the attraction to having such a useful tool in a language you can tweak/edit, I think RRDtool's incredible usefulness came from it being in C++ - thus incredibly fast and scalable. Implementing the same in PHP would of course be possible but would be cumbersome.

Haven't found any PHP alternatives other than interfaces, as you said.
Maybe use something like Cacti for all the data handling and then write a custom grapher.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen anything like what you describe. Pretty much everything I've found is a wrapper or interface. The main RRDTool website has a small directory of these types of projects and they only have info on the various wrappers/interfaces.